# Conditioning a quantum state: why does it have this particular form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator

Can someone please explain the phenomenon of conditioning a quantum state, and why it has this particular form?

An observable $A$ of a quantum mechanical system, described by the density operator $\rho$ is measured. The result returned by the measurement, corresponding to an element of the observable $A$'s spectrum is denoted by $a$.

The systems current state is denoted by $P_a$. This represents a matrix of the same size as $\rho$, but with zeros in all cells except for one (corresponding to the current state.)

After performing this measurement, the density operator has to be altered, as the system is changed by the measurement. Its new form is given by equation (1).

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\rho\mapsto\rho'[a]=\frac{P_a\rho P_a}{Tr[\rho P_a]},
\end{equation}

What I would like to know, is why the new density operator (1) has this particular form. Is there any way I can derive it from other principals?

I first came across the term (conditioning) in this set of lecture slides on page 20:
http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~trumpf/LSslides/Matt_James.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider a pure state represented by a vector $|\psi\rangle$. In this case, the density operator $\rho$ is
$$
  \rho=\frac{|\psi\rangle\,\langle\psi|}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}.
\tag{2}
$$
If a measurement occurs with outcome represented by a projection operator $P_a$, then we should use the state-vector $|\psi'\rangle \equiv P_a|\psi\rangle$ for making the next prediction. The corresponding density operator is
$$
  \rho'=\frac{|\psi'\rangle\,\langle\psi'|}{\langle\psi'|\psi'\rangle} =
  \frac{P_a|\psi\rangle\,\langle\psi|P_a}{\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle}
\tag{3}
$$
using $P_a^\dagger P_a=P_a$ in the last step. To write $\rho'$ in terms of $\rho$, use equation (2) to get
$$
P_a\rho P_a = \frac{P_a|\psi\rangle\,\langle\psi|P_a}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}
\hskip2cm
  Tr[\rho P_a] = \frac{\langle\psi|P_a|\psi\rangle}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}
\tag{4}
$$
and then use these on the right-hand side of (3) 
to get equation (1) in the question.

There are two ways to generalize the preceding derivation to mixed states. The traditional way is to express the density matrix $\rho$ for a mixed state as a weighted sum of pure-state density matrices.

An easier way, which gives the same result, is to recognize that a mixed state *can also be represented by a single state-vector* in an appropriate representation. If the mixed state involves $N$ different pure states, then we can form a new (reducible) representation consisting of the direct sum of $N$ copies of the original one; think of a block-diagonal matrix with $N$ blocks, each of the original size. In this new representation, we can use a single state-vector to represent the desired mixed state. (This is called the **GNS construction**.) With this construction in mind, the derivation (2)-(4) doesn't need to be modified at all for mixed states, because it doesn't actually assume that the state is pure. It only assumes that the state is represented by a single vector.

Typical textbooks don't represent mixed states using a single vector because this requires constructing a new (reducible) representation using larger matrices. Conceptually, it's equivalent; but when writing down explicit matrices on paper, the traditional formulation can be more concise.

Comment: Thank you Dan, and thanks for the in depth explanation at the end.